# When was the origin of the "Nightfall" quotation found?

Tags: isaac-asimov, nightfall

”[Nightfall](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46434)”, a 1941 novelette by Isaac Asimov, is possibly his most well-known and acclaimed work. It was prompted by a discussion between Asimov and John W. Campbell concerning a quotation from Ralph Waldo Emerson:

> If the stars should appear one night in a thousand years, how would
> men believe and adore, and preserve for many generations the
> remembrance of the city of God!

Asimov’s take, as detailed in Nightfall, was that in this situation men would instead go insane.

I read about the genesis of the story more than ten years ago in “[The Early Asimov, Volume 2](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1476194)” (published in 1974), where Asimov wrote that he had never been able to actually track down the source of the quotation. From that, I assumed that it must either be really obscure, or that it had simply been mis-attributed to Emerson. Today, however, it seems to be well-known that the quotation comes from Emerson’s essay “[Nature](https://emersoncentral.com/texts/nature-addresses-lectures/nature2/chapter1-nature/)”. When did the source quotation become known to the sci-fi community - did Asimov live to see its identification?

Comment: Not that it matters at all to the question, but I would have thought "I, Robot" (and the robot stories in general) and "Foundation" (and its sequels etc) are many times more well-known than "Nightfall".

Comment: @IMSoP Maybe "I, Robot", at least now since that Will Smith movie, but a few decades ago "Nightfall" was (I believe) the most reprinted and anthologised SF story ever. As for "Foundation", again, those got a boost in popularity when the later sequels came along. It's dubious.

Comment: @PrimeMover The Will Smith movie was only called that _because_ it was such a well-known title, and thus a saleable brand; they rewrote a previously drafted script to include the references. As for "later boost in popularity", the last "Foundation" prequel was published _nearly three decades ago_, so it's not like we're in the grip of some passing fad. It may be that Nightfall is the most famous _single story_, but the Foundation and Robot series get the top billing in just about every biography I found in a quick web search, just as "Lord of the Rings" would for JRR Tolkein.

Comment: I thought Nightfall is the opposite situation: The stars *disappear* once in a thousand years?

Comment: @tgdavies the local system's *suns* disappear (all set at once) with that frequency, which is what allows 'stars' to be seen

Comment: @AakashM Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The quotation wasn't really obscure. Once *The Early Asimov* was published, where Asimov said that he couldn't find its source, he was immediately informed about it by several readers:

> A few years ago, I admitted in print that I had never been able to find the source of
> the quotation. At once, dozens of letters arrived giving me the precise reference. So please, Gentle Readers, cease and desist from here on in. I now know.
> <sub>from [The Nightfall Effect](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?115626), The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction, March 1976</sub>

As already noted in the question, the quotation is from Emerson’s essay *Nature*. The complete reference is “*Nature*. Boston: James Munroe and Company. 1836.” The essay is available [online](https://emersoncentral.com/texts/nature-addresses-lectures/nature2/chapter1-nature/) and has a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_(essay)).

Comment: So, what is the precise reference?

Comment: @Spencer: The quotation is from the essay “Nature.” The reference is “Nature. Boston: James Munroe and Company. 1836.” Clara has linked it in her question. The essay also has a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_(essay)).

Comment: Thank you @Ubik, I've read a lot of Asimov, but somehow never encountered that essay. Good to know the matter was resolved!

Comment: The 1970s version of "every few years that dang tweet comes back up and my DMs fill with people explaining why it was wrong..."

Comment: You should add the reference to your answer